# Is it likely that intergalactic stars would still retain their planets?

Tags: star, planet, rogue-planet, intergalactic-space

Given that we've discovered hundreds of [intergalactic stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intergalactic_star) (IGs), and that most stars [have planets](https://www.space.com/24894-exoplanets-habitable-zone-red-dwarfs.html), what do we know about the likelihood of IGs retaining their planets after being ejected from their galaxy?

Related to that, what are the chances of [rogue planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet) being intergalactic as well? If there's a planet floating out in intergalactic space, is it more likely to be orbiting a star, or on it's own?

Comment: Whatever processes could fling a star out of the galaxy could probably do the same to a planet. I'd be curious to see if the answer differs between a rogue planet or an ejected star with a planet.

Comment: Why would you think otherwise?  "fling" is relative;  the gravitational force between star and planet is much greater than the external force which ejected the star +planet(s) from a galaxy.

Answer (score 6):

While near encounters with supermassive black holes are bad for the stability of solar systems [citation needed?], many intergalactic stars become intergalactic without a close encounter. They are [part of streams and tidal tails that emerge when galaxies or globular clusters get tidally disrupted by another galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_tide).

Still, even [while encounters with black holes are usually disruptive simulations suggest that some planets may remain around the star](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1446). This is most likely for planets real close to the star, like hot jupiters.